# Table Headers in PDF module in Play Framework

Tags: pdf, playframework

I'm using play framework. I am able to generate the PDF using PDF module. My Problem here is i want to add the table headers in every page. Here is my code

```
<table width="100%" border="1" id="example" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" class="-fs-table-paginate: paginate;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="center"><b>Items</b></th>
                        <th align="center"><b>Quantity</b></th>
                        <th align="center"><b>Unit Price</b></th>
                        <th align="center"><b>Amount(Rs).</b></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
.....
</table>
```

I saw [here](http://www.playframework.org/modules/pdf-0.7/home). i added -fs-table-paginate: paginate; in the class attibute. But the table headers are not continued in the next page.
I don't know how to use this. Can you help me Pl.

EDIT: can anyont help me please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add "-fs-table-paginate: paginate;" to the style attribute, not to the class attribute:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" id="example" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; -fs-table-paginate: paginate;">
```